# How do i give a dynamic key for schema assertion in karate DSL

Tags: karate

I want to match my response by adding a variable in the schema assertion. I tried it by giving '#(value)' but it did not work

```
 * def value = 3

    Then match object ==
    {
         result : {
                      '#(value)'
                               {
                                  firstName : '#string',
                                  lastName : '#string'
                               }
                    }
    }
```

The exception i'm getting says 'path $.result.(#value) actual : null expected                              {
                                      firstName : '#string'
                                      lastName : '#string'
                                   }'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something terribly wrong with your JSON. Are you really trying to use a dynamic key ? That's not possible.

Here's a working example that may help you figure out what you are doing wrong:

```
* def actual = { result: { value: 3, foo: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' } } }
* def value = 3
Then match actual ==
"""
{
  result : {
    value: '#(value)',
    foo: {
      firstName : '#string',
      lastName : '#string'
    }
  }
}
"""
```

(edit:) looks like the ask was indeed for a dynamic key, here is a changed example:

```
* def actual = { result: { 3: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' } } }
* def fun =
"""
function(key) {
  var temp = { result: {} };
  temp.result[key] = { firstName: '#string', lastName: '#string' };
  return temp;
}
"""
Then match actual == fun(3)
```

Comment: I need to use a dynamic key for my request. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: there are plenty of ways. I just updated my answer, this example uses JS. you can also look at string replace to create a string, then type-convert it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped me