# How to manipulate json response schema in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have below json response –

```
{"123": { "id": [], "error": null, "name": "ABC"}}
```

I need to do schema validation. For that I have written below -

- def Schema =  {"123": { "id": [], "error": "#null", "name": "#string"}}

Can I manipulate the value 123 in schema since this value will be created dynamically ? This value is stored in a variable.

Comment: Got the answer here -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049569/how-do-i-give-a-dynamic-key-for-schema-assertion-in-karate-dsl